# What to do when MySQL Database is full

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to launch a web service with an MySQL database. The provider I want to use deliverers an unlimited amount of databases, but the space of one database is limited to 1 GB. Before I start to implement the MySQL with php, I want to ask if there is a mechanism, which automatically creates a new database when one is full and fetches all the databases.

Thanks!

Comment: Change your provider.

Comment: Have you already estimated if 1GB is enough for your data? Do you really need more than that? Large data could also be saved to files and then you can add link to that file to your database. You could also start with 1GB databases and change your service provider later if it seems that you'll need more.

Comment: @SampoSarrala Thanks, it is a good idea to save only links. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

You "could" program a script that create a new database, makes the tables and starting to put the new information into the new database. The problem would be when a old user (for example) wants to log in he has to choose the database his user is created on (unless you want search every single database for him). It will be a lot of loading time wasted because of a (cheap?) hosting solution. Check GoDaddy or another provider who is popular with a lot of users. They are properly the best. Or go check http://www.top10bestwebsitehosting.com/.